# wxpython - Expand list control vertically not horizontally

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have a ListCtrl that displays a list of items for the user to select. This works fine except that when the ctrl is not large enough to show all the items, I want it to expand downwards with a vertical scoll bar rather than using a horizontal scroll bar as it expands to the right.

The ListCtrl's creation:

```
self.subjectList = wx.ListCtrl(self, self.ID_SUBJECT, style = wx.LC_LIST | wx.LC_SINGLE_SEL | wx.LC_VRULES)
```

Items are inserted using wx.ListItem:

```
item = wx.ListItem()
item.SetText(subject)
item.SetData(id)
item.SetWidth(200)
self.subjectList.InsertItem(item)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [wxLC_REPORT](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxlistctrl.html#wxlistctrl) style.

```
import wx

class Test(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        self.test = wx.ListCtrl(self, style = wx.LC_REPORT | wx.LC_NO_HEADER)

        for i in range(5):
            self.test.InsertColumn(i, 'Col %d' % (i + 1))
            self.test.SetColumnWidth(i, 200)


        for i in range(0, 100, 5):
            index = self.test.InsertStringItem(self.test.GetItemCount(), "")
            for j in range(5):
                self.test.SetStringItem(index, j, str(i+j)*30)

        self.Show()

app = wx.PySimpleApp()
app.TopWindow = Test()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: usering wx.LC_REPORT instead of wx.LC_LIST gives me a vertical scroll bar, but all the text items dissapear (although the scroll bar looks about the right size for a complete list...)

Comment: You have to explicitly insert the columns before you can use them. I added an example

Comment: why is your range for i incrementing by 5?

Comment: so that the i+j in the inner loop would go from 0 to 99, it's just a way to generate different cell values.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import wx

class Test(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        self.test = wx.ListCtrl(self, style = wx.LC_ICON | wx.LC_AUTOARRANGE)

        for i in range(100):
            self.test.InsertStringItem(self.test.GetItemCount(), str(i))

        self.Show()

app = wx.PySimpleApp()
app.TopWindow = Test()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: The manual says that self.test.SetColumnWidth(-1, 200) should work but it doesn't, so I don't know. SetColumnWidth works for report mode though, but there you have the hassle of managing columns yourself.

Comment: Or... you can use just one column... maybe even use wxListbox... why complicate things?